# Is encoding and caching gravatar images has any side effects?

Tags: php, caching, seo, memcached, base64

I'm having a comment system which uses gravatar to show user images. I think of caching these images by encoding the resulted image into base64 and storing into memcache.

I'm doing this mainly to avoid querying gravatar often and to avoid load time. So i want to know side effects of using this method both seo and browser wise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so a few points to make here:

**Regarding performance:**

You're likely to see a *performance loss* here for the following reasons:

- **Browsers will cache the images** from Gravatar.com or YourServer.com so anything you do will only affect first load
- Gravatar.com itself is **cached downstream by ISPs** so there's a chance you won't even need to pull all the way from the Gravatar servers
- Gravatar itself has good performance - many **large** sites use it **without performance issues**
- Loading the images from another domain (in this case gravatar.com) **will be done in parallel** to calls on your local domain by most modern browsers, so *you might actually slow things down* by adding more calls to your server which are done serially after a certain number of connection slots are taken (8+ depending on your browser).

It's pretty hard to imagine seeing a performance gain from this. Maybe if you tiled a big collection of gravatar images into one larger png and used CSS to manipulate which ones showed, you'd have fewer server calls and might see a small performance gain, but man that sounds like a huge complexity hit for marginal gains at best.

**Regarding SEO:**

There shouldn't be an SEO issue with this, since **search engines won't know that the image you serve locally is actually a Gravatar image**. Though I suppose some search engines might consider using Gravatar a bit of a bonus as it could "legitimize" you in some way, though this is *entirely speculative* and should not be a factor in your decision making.

Comment: I got few suggestions similar to what mentioned above.. but can i get some mor details on "cached downstream by ISP". Thanks..

Comment: Sure - essentially many ISPs look for situations when a lot of their users are accessing the same content. If a bunch of users are accessing the same Tumblr blog, for example, the ISP may choose to cache those Tumblr blog images themselves (without telling anyone), generally for a short period of time. They do this because if they are keeping the data themselves, they don't have to pay peering costs to grab it from the origin, and they save some money. This incidentally reduces the number of hops needed to access the data because the ISP returns it from their local cache. Make sense?